# jQuery Full calender render events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and Full Calender 1.6.4. Now I am trying to add click event and double click event but I could not success on it.

I tried below work around but it work in FF but not work in IE

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.bind('click', function () {
      var doubleClickOpportunity = 200, // Adjust this to whatever feels right
      clicker = element.data('clicker'); // Holder for the doubleclick setTimeout


      if (clicker) {
        // If there's a setTimeout stored in clicker, then this is a double click
        clearTimeout(clicker);
        element.data('clicker', '');
        element.trigger('doubleclick');
      } else {
        // Otherwise, it's either a single click or the beginning of a double click

        // So set a timer to decide which it is - if the timer runs out,
        // it's just a single click.
        element.data('clicker', setTimeout(function () {
          element.data('clicker', '');
          element.trigger('singleclick');
        }, doubleClickOpportunity));
      }
    });
    element.bind('doubleclick', function (e) {//dblclick
      if (!confirm(Res.deleteEvent))
        return false;


      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
    });
    element.bind('singleclick', function (e) {
      alert("I am click");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link Milind:

This is to bind a scroll event to the calendar maybe it will help you do what you want.

[Fullcalendar mousewheel bind event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023419/fullcalendar-mousewheel-event-prev-next)

Notice that binding events in Firefox is different from Chrome/IE.

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply, I cannot use mousewheel event and my web can be used on mobile or on the pad. So it can become some kind of restriction to those users

Comment: Sure, but meant for you to analize the code so that would help you doing the event binding. I want you to see that binding for example the onclick event to a div/element is different from chrome and firefox.